# Doctrine 2 - Functional Testing

Tags: testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit

Ok, here's the situation. I use Doctrine 2 and PHPUnit.
I have a list of products, each has a category. I want to test findByCategory() method which should obviously return a list of products for specific category.

Quite simple, but I'm not sure how to test this properly. On some places on web I see just simple examples like:

```
$this->assertEquals(4, count($foundProducts));
```

So it just tests the quantity of returned results, but not the actual data.
I also tried this:

```
   foreach($allFoundProducts as $i=>$foundProduct) {
        $this->assertEquals($products[$i], $foundProduct);
    }
```

where $products is a list of entities I've persisted prior to searching.
But it takes a lot of time to accomplish and sometimes even crashes (insufficient memory).

Please advice me the approach you use to make database tests like this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you mean querying by [simple conditions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)?

Comment: I meant functional testing with phpunit. How to make more comfortable testing of repository methods. That might be shortcut methods or custom, does not matter.

Comment: Comparing values returned from DB against an array of expected strings, as you show, is the obvious approach. I think you need to expand your question to explain why that is not good. Why does it "take a lot of time to accomplish"? If it sometimes crashes, what is the error messsage? Is the crash in phpUnit or Doctrine?

Comment: ok, basically what I expected to see in responses is example of how guys out there test against doctrine entities. These are objects, so it's not direct string comparison.

Comment: I do it like this for now:
$this->assertEquals('titleOne', $foundEntity->getTitle())
$this->assertEquals('some description', $foundEntity->getDescription())
....
etc

But if there are alot of fields in entity (also dependent ones) it might be long process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd test the number of returned results (like in your first example), then run through the results and test their type:

```
$this->assertEquals(4, count($foundProducts));

foreach($foundProducts as $product) {
    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyProductEntity', $product);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\Product')->findBy(array('category' => $category));
```

or this:

```
$products = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\Product')->findByCategory($category);
```

Comment: What does it have to do with my question?